# Issue with authentication using a LoginModule

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-console

I am encountering a strange situation with MobileFirst 7.1 where users are occasionally unable to authenticate/login. The only indication that something is awry is a message in the console.log

> [AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID . An invalid user ID or password was specified.

My custom login module uses `com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule` (so to clarify I have a login module which authenticates using LDAP). Like I say everything seems to work most of the time but occasionally users end up in a situation where they are unable to authenticate. I suspect that it is probably related to the session in some way, but that is only a guess based on my investigation.

I have added some logging to my 'secret' adapter which prints the session state to the `console log`, and obviously this appears in the `logs` just before the failed authentication message above, but it is empty ie. the session contains nothing.The user is obviously trying to access a secure adapter at this point, and because they are not authenticated they end up at the login page (form based authentication I should say also).

Anyway, I noticed that although there appears to be no session data, the jsessionid is there and has not changed i.e. it does not change even if I refresh the browser. This may not be an issue in itself of course, but interestingly if I remove this entry and refresh my browser I am able to login successfully.

I am pretty sure that my handler code calls the relevant `success/failure` methods in the correct places but of course there is nothing to stop the user refreshing their browser, which causes them to be re-directed to the login page (the app has been developed using AngularJS so is effectively a single-page navigation model).

The only reproducible test I have been able to come up with is when I login to the MobileFirst console and then try to login to our MF 'desktopbrowser' app. I have read that this situation causes a session-related conflict, but as I say the occasional issue I am seeing is not caused by this (though it may be related).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seems to have been more related to the flow of logic in our application after successfully logging in, than any inherent issue with the MF Platform.

For example when a user refreshes the browser they are effectively still logged in, but because the app (based on logic we have developed) takes the user to the login page on refresh, the user is effectively re-logging in to the same session. If this failed every time it would of course have been easier to pinpoint but it does not. The solution was to force logout on refresh (when the app initialises), thus cleaning up any session data. In future iterations it may of course be better to re-establish the application based on the authenticated session after refresh, but at present that was a step too far.

Another example of this was post login if the subsequent adapter calls failed (e.g. we authenticate and then retrieve profile data from a database), then we were also not logging the successfully authenticated user out.